# Following a Virtual File?

Tags: linux-kernel, tail, sysfs

I'm writing a kernel module to collect some data and printing it out to a file in /sys. I know these files are virtual files, and my understanding is that they are essentially generated every time you open them. My issue is that you can't use `tail -f /sys/myFile` to actively read the output from my module. Is there a proper way to accomplish what I want within the kernel, and barring that is there Any way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: If the file is replaced then tail will not work at all. What's wrong with      watch "cat /sys/myFile"?

Comment: For my application I'm trying to read a "stream" of output data and then process that data. watch works great for human readable output, but is rather ugly for an application.

Comment: and what about `tail -F /sys/myFile`, so it will retry even if the file is not accessible?

Comment: Doesn't work. My understanding is that the kernel just collects the information and provides it whenever you try to access the file. When you tail the file the kernel provides all of the current data, and then never provides the data again since it isn't being accessed Again. Tail -F did the same as -f where it printed the file initially and then did nothing.